# Issues with Shadow Mapping?

Tags: texturing, uv

I'm trying to get a Shadow map for some armor pieces I made and I've been watching this tutorial on how to do it. But some of the options that I need to use to get a good shadow map aren't showing up in my Blender Program. This also includes the *Bake* tab in Render. Which I **need** to for the Shadow mapping process. I've done the UV map already but I can't do the shadow map until I know whats wrong.

Comment: Are you using cycles? Texture baking is currently only available with blender internal.

Answer (score 3):

This is because you are using Cycles.
Texture baking is currently only supported in Blender internal.

This feature is currently under development, you can see [some tests in the bf-cycles mailing list](http://lists.blender.org/pipermail/bf-cycles/2014-January/001752.html).

## Update:

[As of Blender 2.71](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Ref/Release_Notes/2.71/Cycles#Baking_API), Cycles now supports texture baking.  To bake a texture:

1. UV Unwrap the model
2. Add a blank image texture in the *UV/image editor*
3. Add a texture node to your material and select the newly created image
4. Ensure that the texture node is selected
5. Press *Bake* under *Properties panel* > *Render tab* > *Bake*.

Also see:

- [How do I bake a texture using Cycles bake](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/13508/599)
- [Andrew Price's tutorial](http://www.blenderguru.com/tutorials/introduction-baking-cycles/#.VI8CopU5DX4) on cycles baking.