# How do I bake a texture using Cycles bake

Tags: cycles-render-engine, workflow, texture-baking

I created a interior scene and  i don't know how to bake a texture using cycles bake.

Comment: You don't have to be in Object Mode to bake, it will bake in Edit Mode as well (at least it works on my computer). But really make sure that you have selected the texture node and chosen the right image for it. Another reason could be that your object has more than one material assigned to it. In this case they all have to have image textures assigned to them - you could choose one image for all materials of your object if the uv maps don't overlap or different images for different materials.

Comment: @user5875 This doesn't really make sense. Could you explain a little differently? Because that is my case i have a model that I joines the pieces together after texturing them so i could animate them. But how would i bake it then? I have three different images i am using

Answer (score 68, accepted):

With out more detail about the situation, it's hard to say how you might go about this if there are any special considerations.

Here are the basics:

1. [UV unwrap your object](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/6755/599).
2. Create a new image in the *UV/image editor* (<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd> or *Image > New*).
3. Add a texture node to the objects material(s) and select the new image. If there are more than 1 material repeat this for each one of them (easier to copy that Image Texture node and paste it into all materials):

[image]

3. With the texture node selected, press *bake* in *Properties > Render settings > Bake*:

[image]

The color and shading on that object will be rendered to the image specified in the selected texture node.

If you switch to textured shading once this process is complete (for each object), the viewport will look something like this:

[image]

See [the manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/cycles/baking.html) for more detail about the various options.

If you want to bake multiple objects to the same image:

1. UV Unwrap your objects in such a way so that the UV maps don't overlap. An easy way to do this is by pressing <kbd>Space</kbd>*> Smart UV unwrap* or <kbd>Space</kbd>*> Lightmap pack* with all the objects selected.
2. Bake each object with *Clear* disabled so that the existing pixels in the target image aren't erased before the baked shading is overlayed.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I followed you steps but bakeType Combined is not available in my properties settings not able to generate image.

Comment: Thanks , I was using blender 2.7 , i downloaded 2.71 and options are available. Now after pressing bake i get message No  active layer found in the object

Comment: @user1755630 Sounds like it can't find the image to bake to.. Make sure you have an image texture node in all the materials used by the object you are baking. Also make sure they are selected, and are pointing to an image.

Comment: I do this process with one cube object and render engine is set to the Cycles and also have an image texture node but still i get message "No active UV layer found in the object "

Comment: @user1755630 Is it UV unwrapped?

Comment: I am not using UV unwrap but i am using UV image Editor  to do step 3 and 4

Comment: @user1755630 You have to UV unwrap it first (step 1).

Comment: Thanks,Now i am able to generate cycle baking for objects. but not able to get a single texture image for  more than one objects.

Comment: @user1755630 If you disable *Clear* in the bake panel (below the bake button), the baked shading will be overlayed on the existing image.

Comment: I am able to generate texture image one for each object. I am not able to generate a single texture image for multiple objects like your explanation.

Comment: @user1755630 I created multiple texture images (one for each object) for the example in my answer, but it's possible to bake to one image. Updating answer.

Comment: Thanks Sir, This is very helpful for me and now i am able to generate single texture image for multiple objects. I designed a model which have more than 300 objects including wooden floor, Image frames and other, So it looking quite difficult to generate UV unwrap for each object and separate there mesh on UV editor.

Comment: @user1755630 You could temporarily join the objects (`Ctrl J`) and arrange the UV islands with `Ctrl P` in the image editor. Then separate the objects with `P` > *Loose parts* in the 3D view.

Comment: Hello Sir, I created a single texture image using 3 objects these are torus, Cube and Plane.color is different for each object,I used that model and image in Open gles but it is not looking like designed model blender.Is there any mistake made by me?

Comment: I get the message " No active image found in material object for body "0". I did all the steps as you said, in cycles, image texture etc.

Comment: Hah, you got me. I didn't have a image on all materials.

Comment: @gandalf3 what if i want to bake it to different images because my model had different textures and uvs and then i joined the objects of the model so i could animate it. So is there a way I can bake it so all three of my textures and images that i used show up?

Comment: @Nolan Yes, I think that should work, but I haven't tested it. There's nothing preventing a single object from having multiple UV maps, multiple textures, or multiple materials, so it's certainly possible. Whether or not blender properly merges all of those when joining objects is what remains to be seen

Comment: @gandalf3 so how would I do it?  do you know? Would I just add that node talked about in the answer to each material?

Comment: @Nolan Yes, and point it at different image files to your liking. (e.g. point the node in material A to target image A, the node in material B to target image B, etc). Baking multiple materials/objects to one image should also work, but be sure your UV maps don't overlap.

Comment: Minor point of confusion that can cause the "No active image found in material.." error that @Rick mentioned. In step three, adding a new texture node, create a new image in that new texture node and then select the texture node. Then it will work. In my case I created a new texture node and selected it without creating a new image

Answer (score 1):

You have to be in object mode to bake. So unwrap in edit mode, create your new image in uv image editor by splitting a window, name it and save it on your hd. Now, go into object mode, select the image texture node so that it is highlighted in orange, then hit bake. Then, re save the image under the image drop down. I had the same problem.

Then, I got a new problem that required me add an image texture to another object in the scene before bake the current one.

Comment: *"You have to be in object mode to bake"* not necessarily. When baking esp. passes like diffuse or other colors bake will work in Edit or pretty much any interaction mode