# Baking a normal map, Cycles or Blender render?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, blender-internal-render-engine, texture-baking

I need to bake a normal map from a high-poly model to a low poly, and I wanted to know, what should I use, Cycles or the standard Blender render?

I guess it should be the same, more or less? If I bake a normal map from Blender render, it will work in Cycles too, right?

Also, I can't find a tutorial or an explanation on how to bake a normal map in Cycles, does anyone know one? I did find one on Blender render.

Comment: You'll end up a better artist if you can learn both.  And yes, there is a Normal Map node in Cycles that accepts Blender Object space maps and also the Tangent maps are consistent for both renderers.

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/13508/599

Comment: blenderguru just released a [tutorial for cycles baking](http://www.blenderguru.com/tutorials/introduction-baking-cycles)