# Is there a way to export the built in textures as a UV map?

Tags: texturing

Basically, I am making a weapon for Skyrim, I already finished the mesh itself and used the cycles render materials and surface nodes as the texture. Now, I have run into a wall, I can't seem to find a way to export the existing texture . Is there a way to do this or is this an exercise in futility?

Comment: you could bake the material..

Comment: could you please document the steps that you have gone through so far.  On the one hand, it sounds as if you already baked the texture but on the other hand;  If you did that already then you would have a texture that only needs to be saved and that would be very easy compared to what you already would have done.  It would help if you load pictures and outline the steps so someone can help you through the rest.  You're question leaves too many unknowns as it is.  As a general guideline, try to make your question as clear and detailed as you would like the answer to be.

Comment: [This answer](http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/13509/935) should get you started