# How to transform the face of an object in a texture?

Tags: texturing, objects, vertices

I have below a cube type object that has very sharp faces. These faces contain 3 different colors (3 different types of purple) and I want to know if there is a way to transform these faces in a 2D texture so I could then delete the sharp faces and add the texture to a flat face, without loosing the aspect and forms of the colors. Is there a way to do that?

[image]

Comment: Do you want to convert the shading to a 2D texture? (Try [baking](http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/13508/599))

Comment: I want to convert the faces that are selected into a 2D texture so I could keep the colours and the forms of the faces