# How to create a 3D model of an object and then put it on the Internet in a 3D viewer

Tags: modeling

With my startup team-members, we're looking to build a 3D model of our product, to put it on our website, and then be able to move it 360°, is it possible to do this?

Does it cost a lot?

Thank you for your Help.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about general 3D business, not about creating things inside blender.

Comment: If it's not handled properly in Blender then it won't work.  Saying this is off topic is like saying that people who want to make a still render are off topic if they plan to post it on a website.  Blender can handle this and there is no reason why someone should not be able to ask for help with this.

Comment: @MarcClintDion I was under the impression the OP was not asking *how*, so much as how hard would it be/who should do it. (and not necessarily if it's possible in blender specifically).

Comment: I get the impression that he is assessing Blender's capabilities and whether or not Blender can generate assets which can be used outside of Blender.  This is important since investing time and effort into software that is incompatible with other tools would be frustrating.  The part about looking for team members should be edited out.  I'll do that now.  That's definitely out-of scope.  The following website has 2 sections where you can ask for help, there's Paid and Volunteer.  http://blenderartists.org/forum/forum.php

Comment: @gandalf3 I agree with MarcClintDion, I don't think it should be closed (plus it has 2 answers).

Comment: If you would like more freedom, i.e. programmatic interaction capabilities, have a look at [three.js](http://threejs.org/), which is able to display `*.obj` files from Blender using WebGL.

Comment: @PGmath I didn't get the impression they were asking about how to do this in blender, but perhaps I'm wrong. Now that the question has been edited, it seems fine as far as fitting in the scope of this site. However, I'm not sure if it's what the OP intended. Hopefully the OP could clarify?

Answer (score 7):

This is fairly easy to do if you are using the Blender in combination with Sketchfab since there is an Addon that is included with Blender which sends the model directly to the website for you.(Although it can be buggy so I'll show how to do it without the Addon)

At the time of writing, the free version of SketchFab allows you to upload .blend files that are a maximum of 50MB.

When the model is ready to be uploaded, you can pack all the textures individually or write a script that can iterate through all the textures and pack them automatically.  Once this is done then the .blend file will contain copies of the images.
This will be important for loading the scene file to Sketchfab, otherwise you can load them manually afterwards.

[image]

Next, go to the SketchFab website and locate the blue **Upload** button and then use the directory menu to select the .blend file that you would like to upload.

[image]

It's that simple to load a model, here it is shown in the interactive 3D viewer.

[image]

Now if you want to embed the model and viewer into a website click the *Embed* button and copy the contents of the mini popup dialogue.

[image]

Now paste this into the HTML code of your website as shown in the following image.

[image]

Here's what the page looks like after the code is embedded.  btw, the low quality banding is from the animated .gif, not sketchFab or Blender.

[image]

There is a page here that has some extra information on preparing the material so it will function correctly with exporters/SketchFab.

[Exporting cycles rendered models to be used in opengl](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/19299/exporting-cycles-rendered-models-to-be-used-in-opengl/19326#19326)

Comment: Can also make mention of http://p3d.in.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is possible and it doesn't cost a lot. I recommend using Unity3D 5. Unity 3D is a game engine that can run on almost any platform. It can also run on any web browser if you install the Unity plugin.

If the user doesn't have the Unity plugin installed, it will ask the user to install it.

With the latest Unity3D 5 released, it can run anything on Website without Plugin. I think that Unity is the best way to do this. It uses the new web technology called "WebGL" to render 3D Objects, instead of its plugin. WebGl is supported everywhere.

Short answer:

1) Model your product in using Blender.  Then [BAKE](http://www.blenderguru.com/tutorials/introduction-baking-cycles/#.VH3h4JUtDX4) your 3D model.

2) Install Unity 5 and import your model. Add a rotating C# script to it that detects mouse input and rotates your model.

3) Build the project as [WebGl(Preview)](http://blogs.unity3d.com/2014/10/14/first-unity-game-in-webgl-owlchemy-labs-conversion-of-aaaaa-to-asm-js/) format and you are good to go.

License:
Unity is free as long as your company make < 100,000 every year. If you make bigger than that, you are required to buy a Unity license which cost only $1500. Its worth it.

For the script I mentioned in #2, You can just Google "Unity Rotate 3D Object with Mouse". You will find many scripts.

20 Minutes of Unity3D tutorial for your team should be fine t o accomplish this.