# Importing a material from blender to unity

Tags: texturing, export, unity, blend-files

I made a low poly tree model that doesn't use textures and instead uses 2 colors and i imported it into unity 5.3.4 and the tree model imports itself without the colors. What i want to know is how to import the colors or how to get those colors that i have in blender to unity or if i have to make a texture has just those colors. I use cycles render and to import my models i save the .blend file in the assets folder in unity.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Note that you can [approximate your cycles material in unity via texture baking](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/24422/599), but it won't be exact.

Answer (score 2):

Cycles rendering isn't used for realtime objects (games/apps/etc). Those types of object rely on uv textures, diffuse colors, specular colors, etc.

The biggest difference is that realtime objects are calculated using 1 bounce of light. It's fast enough to render in engines like unity. Cycles uses multiple light bounces. It makes it look more realistic, but isn't fast enough for those engines.

To answer your question, switch to Blender Internal if you're using the object for games. Test a quick render to make sure you have all materials correctly attached, as switching from cycles may call for some extra work. If it works in the render, exporting to .obj or .fbx should work.

Also note that if you export to .fbx, the textures won't automatically be on the model, you'll need to relink them to the model in Unity.