# Multiple materials on one exported model in UE4?

Tags: mesh, materials, export

I want to have two meshes that can have their own material applied in Unreal Engine 4, and have them be exported as the same file. Example: A chair that can have a material for the seat itself, then a different one for the legs of the chair but still be the same model. I tried just exporting with the multiple meshes in the same scene, but the material gets applied to the whole object rather than the specific part I want to materialize. Any info regarding this subject is appreciated. Thanks in advance and have a great day :)

Comment: Welcome to the site. As the perfomance of the game will depend on the draw calls you want to minimize them as much as possible. The draw calls depend particulalry on amount of materials. From this and also other reasons it's often recommended to bake all the materials' colors into single diffuse map and assinging it to a single material in the engine.

Comment: Related - http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/24422/export-cycles-material-to-unity

Comment: I was looking for this information and scoured a bit before I found it. Here are two videos on how you could complete either method to have multiple materials in one object. Multiple material instances
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=amqaknw-NxA UV Mapping
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AS_YYaIXPXA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want a mesh that has 2 different materials applied to it?
Then just model 1 mesh in blender. Select the faces that you want and assign them to "Material 1". Then select the other faces and assign them to "Material 2".

Export as an .fbx and import in UE4. UE4 will automatically make 2 material slots on your mesh. (They are called "elements")
Then you can just drag and drop one material into one slot and another material onto the other slot.

Comment: This works for me sometimes, but most of the time, it does not. Is there any sneaky button I'm forgetting to push? (I'm using Blender 2.80 if that helps).