# Export textures + Nodes into one image?

Tags: export

I am using blender for an online game (Roblox) and they only allow you to use one image for textures.

I made a rock mesh, with a pretty good texture and some nodes that make it look great, but without the nodes and texture it looks horrid.

Mesh + Textures + Nodes in Blender
[image: IN BLENDER!]

I looked up how to export textures but nothing seems to work.
I tried UV Unwrapping but (im a noob) and keep getting stuck on this...
(This is in UV/Image Editor)
[image: Picture2]

I tried most of the answers on this site, but then this happened in the game...
[image: Doesnt look good at all]
UV Unwrap
[image: Is this okay??]

Wrap up;
How do I export Nodes, and Textures **into one image**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I bake a texture using Cycles bake](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/13508/how-do-i-bake-a-texture-using-cycles-bake)

Comment: Note that exporting diffuse colors and bumps on surface into one image isn't possible, there will be 2 images required for that

Comment: [my answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/95977/2217) explains why you are not getting the export you want.

Comment: Edited the question,

Comment: With that kind of UV map it's not surprising. It also isn't matching with image shown there (I suppose bake) so likely bake was done using another UV map. Note also to use as much texture space (that square where everything in UV editor happens) as possible