# Export shader nodes from Blender to Unreal Engine or Unity

Tags: scripting, materials, node-editor

I would like to know if there is any way to export the shader nodes I created in blender to Unity or Unreal engine.

Thank you in advance

Comment: What did you mean export? Use those value and mock another shader in Unity? As long as Unity didn't adopt EEVEE or Cycles as the rendering engine. We can't actually directly export the material nodes.

Comment: The only solution is to bake the materials, you can't export procedural materials between different render engines if they weren't build specifically with that relationship in mind, like Eevee was to Cycles.You should check : https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/24422/export-cycles-material-to-unity?rq=1

Comment: I understand, I will then try to remake the shaders in the other engines or bake the materials, thanks for the help!