# Having problems with exporting to OBJ

Tags: cycles-render-engine, export

Hey guys i have a question i did a house model and i have a plenty of good materials with normal map, multiply shaders is there anyway i can join this all together to make a bake in order for me to export it to an OBJ?

Comment: OBJ (Wavefront) file itself only stores geometry data, it does not keep anything regarding materials or textures.  However you can always use other formats like .fbx which supports textures and materials.

Comment: [.fbx export why there are no materials or textures?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures), second paragraph.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/90096 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/13508 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/24422

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Materials and shaders are not transferable with Obj format. It does not allow to export Blender materials and shaders. All it can do is to export a simple Phong shader plus some textures. And not everything can be baked into a texture. So the general answer is no.

You could bake all the color information into a single diffuse map. Use Cycles and bake with method Combined. Also a normal map should arrive. But the rest you most probably need to reassing in your target platform then.

Make sure to use relative paths so that the textures are not missing.

Comment: and in FBX there is any other way i can export the materials and shaders and all that stuff?

Comment: FBX can transfer a bit more. Simply try it out. But also this format is not able to transfer a Blender material with all its content one to one. Blender Materials is a Blender internal feature. Same goes for all other major 3D apps.