# how to export objects with materials from blender to unity?

Tags: modeling, export, unity, color

so i made a small street in blender and colored it. i need to use this street in unity with colors but when i export the street as .fbx and put it in unity, it has no colors. so i searched this in the internet and people said things like "export it with the materials" but i dont know how to do it. can somebody help me? [image: street in the unity]

Comment: You can't just "export" your scene to fbx. You'd have to bake the textures depending on the chosen render pipeline and the available shaders in unity, e.g. universal render pipeline, roughness vs. specular. Related or dupe: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/24422/export-cycles-material-to-unity