# Recommended Blender rendering engine for game assets production

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, export, blender-internal-render-engine, collada

I want to produce models with animations and skinning for a custom game engine. The engine supports import of assets in Collada or FBX format through the Assimp open source library.

Typically the models will be vehicles with moving parts and animated people inside. The models will typically have a diffuse texture, and maybe a normal map, as well as some basic material parameters, such as specularity and transparency/alpha.

The in-game rendering will use custom GLSL shaders, so I will probably not be able to use much of the material data from Blender.

With these preconditions, what rendering engine should I use in Blender when producing the assets? I have used both the default engine and Cycles. Cycles tend to look better during modeling, but I get various problems when exporting, such as textures not showing up (at least when exporting to FBX).

In short, what material system will translate best when exporting to Collada or FBX?

Comment: This question is primarily opinion based, which is not a good fit for the Stack Exchange model - this would be better of over at BlenderArtists.org; That said, what you should do is probably using Cycles and baking the textures.

Comment: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/19299/exporting-cycles-rendered-models-to-be-used-in-opengl/19326#19326 I posted several answers on how to bake using both BI and Cycles if you want to look through them.