# Cycles Node maps to image

Tags: cycles-render-engine

How would i export cycles node maps and turn them into images?
I am trying to port a model into the Source engine and i want to have the same node maps. I looked everywhere and nobody has figured it out yet.

Comment: Do you mean Baking? http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/14418/1853 https://www.blender.org/manual/render/workflows/bake.html and http://www.blenderguru.com/tutorials/introduction-baking-cycles/

Comment: Yes, but when i tried it blender just exported a black image.

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/24422/export-cycles-material-to-unity/24438#24438 and http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/19299/exporting-cycles-rendered-models-to-be-used-in-opengl/19326#19326