# Baking error no UV coordinates

Tags: rendering, node-editor, texture-baking, baking

It says there is no UV texture on the two materials part of the object, but if I add the a UV texture I will have to remove the cloud texture needed for the displace modifier. Could someone look at it please and tell me what I can do to bake the object the way it looks?

Here is my [.blend](https://www.dropbox.com/s/7as4voewm8cr6gw/Banana5th%20attempt.blend?dl=0)

Comment: You shouldn't have to remove the cloud texture..

Comment: It works fine for me. http://www.pasteall.org/pic/81720 See http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/13508/599

Answer (score 1):

I believe he thinks you have connect the image texture in the nodes(leading to remove other textures) to another that's not the case just add it somewhere in it that's all.

Go to each material in the node setting and just shift-a > texture > image texture and link the unwrapped texture to it done.