# How can you save Blender materials as image files?

Tags: texturing, materials, image

How can I change my object material to an image texture? I want to be able to export a blender material applied to an object as (for example) a .png file. Is this possible ?

Comment: Well can't you just assign this material to a plane, make the camera orthographic and place it on top of the plane, then hit "render" and save the image as .png?

Comment: This is called *baking*. Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/13508/599

Answer (score 18, accepted):

One way to do this is if you are using the default internal render engine is to generate a *UV Map* from an object hosting the material and then bake the texture to an image.

Open the *UV/Image Editor* and create a new image (you can set the output resolution from here), next select the object, <kbd>Tab</kbd> into *Edit* mode and press <kbd>U</kbd> to generate a uv map, for very simple models you can use the default *Unwrap* or *Project from View* (for more complicated objects it's also best if you use a simple object with the material on it as opposed to unwrapping a detailed mesh) go to the *Render* tab and under *Bake*, you can set the *Bake Mode* to *Textures* (if you are using a custom texture) or just use *Full Render*.

In the image below, I created a simple green material and added a wood texture to it and the did a *Full Render* bake, the result is shown in the *Image Editor* on the left. After that, use the *Image* menu to save it.

[image]

Comment: How is this done in 2.8?  I tried to do as suggested but got told No active image found in material slot....which is expected because I am trying to use those process to create such an image so that I don't have to use the material.

Answer (score 0):

You can go to *File > External Data > Unpack all Into Files*, and it saved the images as image files in the folder the Blender file was.