# Generated material in Blender, export to Unity

Tags: texturing, node-editor, uv-image-editor, unity

I'm trying to do something I believe should be very simple. But I am also very new to blender.

I have created a material, very simply, and applied it to an object (through the node editor - sorry if my vocabulary is off). It works just fine in the Blender Renderer. 
[image]
It fits perfectly on the object, but I want to now export this from Blender, to be used in Unity.

I have a UV map of this object. But that doesn't help if I can't get the image of the material I generated. Sorry if this is unclear. 
[image]
Basically, I want to generate the appropriate image, that (if used with my UV map of the object) would produce what I'm seeing rendered here in Blender.

Perhaps I'm going about it backwards, but this seems like I'm just missing some last step of this workflow. Ultimately this would be used in Unity; not sure if that changes things.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/13508/how-do-i-bake-a-texture-using-cycles-bake/13509#13509

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/90096/how-can-i-convert-a-node-made-material-into-an-image-texture/91784#91784

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/24340/how-can-you-save-blender-materials-as-image-files/24342#24342

Comment: Thank you - found the answer in this one: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/24340/how-can-you-save-blender-materials-as-image-files/24342#24342 The key word I was looking for is "baking."