# How to fix no active image found in material slot

Tags: texturing, uv, texture-baking

I'm learning the texturing,give color, uv unwrap and baking through tutorial on youtube.

Somehow i got this error "no active image found in material slot"

( link 1: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fhy0F.jpg )
( link 2: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gX5si.jpg )

tried to solve it by reading forum but still cannot understand what does it mean by material slot, let alone to fix it.

what did i do wrong? need help.
version used: 2.8

Comment: Does this help ? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/31071/need-some-help-baking-no-active-image-found-in-material?rq=1

Comment: [How to upload an image to a post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To bake into an image you need to have it selected in the Node editor

you don't have to connect it to anything

just an image texture node then select the image you want to bake on and make sure that the node is selected

Comment: thx, here's the result.
(link: https://imgur.com/a/WIsCdPz )

I got a weird looking uv texture with black and white. what has actually happened?
did i miss something?

Comment: Happy to help but I can't see the results.
If it solved your problem, consider accepting my answer as it would help me too

Comment: Depends on what you are backing
If you are backing the diffuse color, then your model should be well lit