# Extract Texture from a 3D blender model

Tags: texturing, uv, objects, image

As part of a project, I want to convert a 3D Model into a 2D image, my goal is to extract the texture from the model using blender.

I know UV unwrapping goes by the following steps:

1. Import object.
2. Unwrap object.
3. Apply the image(texture) in UV image editor.

[image: UV Unwrapping]

Now my question is, does a procedure exist to do the following steps:

a. Import object which already has texture.

b. Extract the texture from this object and save as an image file.
[image: Texture extraction]

Well I am new to Blender and I apologize if my question seems trivial. Thanks in advance

Comment: Generally when you have a model, your texture is a separate image file. Why would you want to do something to extract it, if all you have to do is locate the file? Unless you mean procedurally, then it's a bit different. You just need to be a bit more specific. What do you want to do this for?

Comment: What you are looking for is called **Baking** in cycles: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/13508/how-do-i-bake-a-texture-using-cycles-bake

Comment: @Tardis : Alright, My project is based on 3D cameras. The system i developed gives me a 3D model of an object for e.g a doll head. Now my next goal is to extract the texture from this object. 

As you can see, I am not using blender to apply the texture in the first place.

Comment: Thank you @cegaton, I will read the article about Baking.

Comment: @Srijith How are the colors represented on the 3D model you have? Vertex colors? It should be possible to unwrap the model and bake the texture as cegaton suggested

Comment: @gandalf3 I just read about baking and it seems to be what I am looking for. Let me try it out and I'll get back to you guys with the results. Thank you

Comment: Has the baking done the job? If the object already has the material applied and it displays correctly inside of Blender then you should be able to simply find it in the UV Image editor and save it as a seperate external file? Is it possible to upload the file for us to take a look at? :)

Answer (score 3):

Im New to blender and I found an easy way: (first time ever in blender)

-Open blend file

-open uw window

-in the icon with a photo , search for the textures

-once selectes just click on the file button

-export it