# UV Image Editor won't allow me to search for textures

Tags: texturing, uv, uv-image-editor

I have a [3D tea cup model](https://github.com/hotmeatballsoup/blender-repo/blob/master/TeaCup.blend) that I've loaded into Blender v2.78 and I'm trying to access its 2D texture so I can play around with the texture and make some changes to it.

So I had a similar question to [this one](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/32888/extract-texture-from-a-3d-blender-model) and I'm struggling to follow the accepted answer because of what I'm seeing in Blender.

When I open that BLEND file in Blender I see:

[image]

I've confirmed that the top window is the UV Editor. When I click on the "*Icon with a photo*" (which is instruction #3 in the accepted answer to that other question, I'm trying to "*search for textures*", but as you can see it will only allow me to choose **View**, **Paint** or **Mask**:

[image]

All I'm trying to do is to extract out the texture to this tea cup, any ideas what my next step should be?

---

#### Update

I selected **UV Editing** layout and see this:

[image]

So the options I'm seeing are:

1. Render Results
2. Viewer Node
3. Alexs_Apt_8k.jpg
4. wooden_fence_texture.jpg

None of these seem applicable to my *tea cup*!!! Again, I'm just trying to get the 2D texture image of the tea cup model that I see in the **Camera Persp** screen below the UV Editing window.

Comment: And where is your texture located in your computer? Or you just need to save what you see in the 3D view?

Comment: I think you don't want to assign a texture but want to render the scene to get the resulting image?

Comment: Thanks @JanKadeřábek (+1 for both) - I might be fundamentally misunderstanding Blender here, so maybe I am confusing you! I *assumed* the texture was **embedded** inside the BLEND file, am I correct? If so, I have the same BLEND file saved on my laptop as what I posted on GitHub (link is provided above). And if not, please let me know! That will clear up all my confusion!!!

Comment: I also have access to an MTL file that came with the tea cup, might the texture/image be in there?

Answer (score 1):

Your very top editor is the uv image editor, but to use it you need to drag that whole bar down to see the window - what you think is the uv image editor is actually a node editor, and below that is the 3d view and then the timeline.

Use ctrl-left/right arrow to get to the UV Editor layout, and then use the button next to the 'New' button to browse that available images in the file - if there is an image texture in the cup's material, then it shoudl be available to open.
[![

edit: your material for the cup doesn't have an image node hooked up, and there isn't an image to go on the cup material in the file. Looks like you need to add an image node and then open the image you say you have in the mtl file, or go back to blender render and try to import the object with the mtl intact to get the image in the material.
Image as reference for the UV Image Editor][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b4gy0.png)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b4gy0.png)

Comment: Thanks @Craig D Jones (+1) - please see my update. I took an educated guess at what you mean by "*dragging the whole bar down*" but as you can see in that screenshot, I'm still not seeing what you're describing. I also tried the `Ctrl+Left/RightArrow` like you mentioned but that didn't work either (although I'm on a MacBook Pro so perhaps Blender responds differently on Apple machinery). Any other ideas? Thanks again!

Comment: Where the new screen says 'Custom' at layout, click the icon to the left to see a drop down of available layouts and switch to the UV Editing layout.

Comment: Thanks again @Craig D Jones (+1) I think I'm *almost* there. Please see my latest update...I'm not in the UV Editing layout, but the grid on the left-hand side of the screen is empty. Any idea how I can get it to load the 2D texture image for my teacup? What I'm really trying to do is export it as JPG/PNG so I can edit it externally and then reimport it later (after I've edited it). Thanks again!

Comment: See my last edit - added a screen shot - if the image is in the material, then you should be able to call it by clicking the icon to the left of 'New' and choose it from the list of images in file.

Comment: Thanks again, *so close*! Please take a look at my latest screenshot/update. Looks like perhaps this tea cup model *doesn't* have a texture...is that possible? I uploaded the BLEND file to GitHub if you or anyone wants to take a look.

Comment: I have edited my answer for you, it should be now clear how this works in Blender.

Answer (score 0):

All images in the .blend (packed and external) are available via this select menu in UV/Image Editor or by pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> there.

[image]

You can also drag&drop an image from Windows Explorer to the UV/Image Editor.

If you want to copy your .blend to another computer and access the images you are using in the project, you need to:

- copy all the images to some folder on the other computer and use *File* > *External Data* > *Find Missing Files* to re-link them

  [image]

  *or*
- embed the textures to the .blend, which can be done:

  - individually for each image by clicking on *UV/Image Editor* > *Image* > *Pack Image*

    [image]
  - globally for all external assets by navigating to *File* > *External Data* > *Automatically Pack Into .blend*

    [image]

Personally, I always make a folder for my Blender project and copy necessary images to the project's subfolder called "textures".
Then you can simply zip the project folder and copy it to another computer. The .blend will still have access to the textures because it uses relative paths in default.

Answer (score 0):

While there aren't any images packed into the blend file, the mug model does not use any image textures.

The material for the mug is a simple mix of diffuse and glossy using a layer weight node to control the mixing.

[image: mug material]

The two missing images are used for the environment and the table.