# Cycles: Trying to bake all materials to one image, but it creates an image for each material?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, uv, baking

I'm doing the normal:

1. Create new UV map.
2. Unwrap
3. Make A New Image in UV editor.
4. Bake -> Diffuse Color

Again, instead of putting them all onto one image, it makes like 4 or 5 images for each material. All combined together, it would be perfect, but this obviously isn't.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Related - http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/13508/how-do-i-bake-a-texture-using-cycles-bake. In Cycles, you add Image Texture node to the material you'd like to bake to and it must be selected.

Comment: @MrZak Thanks! I tried that already. I mean, the instructions are simple, I don't get why they keep baking to 5 different files instead of the one... :(

Answer (score 2):

I've solved my own issue. In Cycles, you must create a floating (not connected) Image Texture node and select it **FOR EACH MATERIAL**. I was creating a new material, not doing this for every existing one. Doh -- thanks!