# Create UV mapped texture within blender from multi-textured object

Tags: texturing, uv

From what I have seen on-line, one method to get an object textured as desired is to create a separate material for each face of the object and apply a unique texture to each face.

For example if you wanted to create a dice without a UV mapped texture to hand, you could simply use a cube, get images for each of the 6 sides and apply those images to each side of the dice.  The alternative as I understand it, is to export a UV outline to GIMP or photoshop and remember which way is up for each side of the dice and construct a single texture.

So my question is, is it possible for blender to project the final objects textures (you created using multiple materials) onto a flat UV mapped surface so that you can then save that texture and apply it as a single texture to a new cube later?

Essentially going from a complete 3D object using multiple textures, to a complete 3D object using a single texture.

Comment: As it's sounds you are looking for [baking](https://www.blender.org/manual/render/workflows/bake.html). Related - http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/13508/how-do-i-bake-a-texture-using-cycles-bake

Comment: Yes, indeed baking does look like the sort of thing I'm after, but does this apply to a multi-textured object?

Comment: It does - if you bake an object with any setup to an object with a proper UV, it will project the result of whatever setup you have on to the target mesh. This, by extension, means you can use however many multitexture setups you want, and it should output your desired result.