# How to make walls be covered with tiles with different shading?

Tags: objects, faces

I am new to blender and already searched on google but didn't find a solution. I would like to create a round ball (and remove the lower half part but I know how to do this) and fill the face of it with flat objects like squares or triangles...

(triangles will look like:

```
\/\
```

so two triangles build one square)

Here is a picture from cerebro from the x men films. It is build of squares. I would like to achieve something like this:

[image: reference image]

Comment: Thankyou for your comment ;) I added a picture. Two triangles in different directions together build a square.

Comment: /\  and \/ next to each other. it's a bit difficult to explain because i am from germany ;)

Comment: I think there're 2 main steps - first, by making walls (which form a spherical or non-spherical, whatever object) appear as tiles, and then make those tiles being shaded like that. I'd say you should construct tiles somehow first, see [this question](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/49339/how-to-make-lines-visible-on-rendering) for some details, and once tiles are ready you make them each shaded differently.

Comment: Are you trying to get something similar to this? http://i.stack.imgur.com/m828W.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

An icosphere is a triangulated sphere.
Subdivide for more faces.

[image]

Comment: That's one of the results i wanted to get. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the site, famemaker. You might want to take the [tour](https://blender.stackexchange.com/tour), and review the [help center](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help). One thing you will learn about Blender that I don't recall seeing when I looked at those pages is that given just about any task one can imagine in Blender, there are multiple, equally useful ways to accomplish it. The way I would make that wall in Blender is to start with a large radius cylinder, say a radius of 50 with 150 vertices in the circumference, or a radius of 100, with about 300 vertices in circumference, and in both cases a suitable height. Using edge select in edit mode, I'd subdivide the height into the necessary number of rows that make the height of the individual segments about the same as their width, and scale the rows of vertices demarcating individual margins to achieve the look of the interior of a tiled sphere.