# Is there away to export textures created with nodes to fbx?

Tags: export

I had my monkey textured with nodes, and did an fbx export. Usually fbx takes my materials in blender render, but in cycles, the nodes don't transfer so there is no texture. Is there a file I can export in so the nodes come? Thank you so much to all my helpers!

Comment: You need to bake the textures. See: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/13508/how-do-i-bake-a-texture-using-cycles-bake

Answer (score 3):

No there is not, nodal materials are not supported (by any exporter afaik), this would require some generic work first to be able to 'translate' those advanced shading representations in the basic, 'fixed' shaders supported by FBX and similar formats (and results would likely not be that great anyway)…

Answer (score 0):

It depends. It would be quite helpful if we would know more about your material setup. Screenshots are always helpful.

If it's basic diffuse textures you want to "export" you can of course bake them. There should be plenty tutorials around the net by now.

However, if you want to export a complex material setup with all its attributes, the answer is no. And I doubt that this will ever happen.

Edit: This is how I bake diffuse maps composed from two textures and some nodes. The texture node to the right that is not connected to anything is used to specify the image I want to bake to.

[image]