# Exporting to FBX, Top is Transparent and no Materials

Tags: export

A noob to this. The goal is to export to an FBX file so that it can be converted to a WT3 file that can be used by Wikitude. I'm using Blender and was able to figure out how to apply a texture and material to the can. Then, the model is exported as an FBX file using Blender. However, I have two problems: 1. The top of the can is transparent and 2. The material (can print) isn't exported.

Any help and/or direction would be much appreciated.

Original Model: https://www.turbosquid.com/3d-models/free-3ds-model-simpsons-duff-beer--/587372

Screenshot of what's happening:
[image]
Left: Blender showing that the material has been applied and that the top of the can is solid.

Right: Using [Autodesk FBS Review](https://www.autodesk.com/products/fbx/fbx-review) to view the FBX file. Note that there's no Duff label and that the top of the can is either transparent or not solid.

Blender file: [image]

Note: There are many questions and answers saying that FBX files should only contain the model and not include textures. However, the [Wikitude 3D Encoder](https://www.wikitude.com/products/wikitude-sdk-features/wikitude-3d-encoder/) requires everything in an FBX file. Hence, the challenge that I'm having here. I might be misunderstanding the workflow in which case, please let me know.

Any help that I can get with both or either dilemma would be much appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Also see https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures or https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/49463/is-there-away-to-export-textures-created-with-nodes-to-fbx

Comment: Thank you for the responses. I've seen all of those posts and they didn't help. For the transparency, rotation and scales are already set. For the export, those were the posts that I was referencing in which there were other questions and answers about FBX not containing the texture/materials.