# Blender object with two UVS

Tags: uv, export, texture-baking, baking, uv-image-editor

I am trying to load in a blender file and export it as an OBJ file with with materials.

The approach I am trying to use is to bake all of the materials (using cycles) into a diffuse and specular (glossy) map. This seems to work well for simple objects, however once I am using an object with textures, I am running into problems.

First I combine all of the objects together into a single mesh (ctrl J) so I can have a single map for all of them.

In order to bake the materials, I have to unwrap the mesh, create an image texture in each material, assign it to the target image I create, then bake the diffuse and specular individually.

When I try to use textures for my materials, I run into problems. I am unable to unwrap the mesh for baking because this will mess up the original UVs for displaying the object.

Is there any way I can keep the starting UVs, then create a new set of UVs for baking? Or is there a better approach for solving this problem?

EDIT: I believe this is duplicate. Sorry. Just found:
[How to remap my UV without messing with textures already applied to a mesh?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/50650/how-to-remap-my-uv-without-messing-with-textures-already-applied-to-a-mesh)