# problem exporting model with texture

Tags: materials, export, import

I have a basic problem (I guess). I'm just using the default cube, I added a material then a texture I chose the default "marble" pattern. When I render it, it looks like it should. However, when I export the object (tried all different formats), then import the model back into blender, there is no marble pattern on the cube.

Comment: To my knowledge, (could be wrong) nodes are a cycles only thing, so exporting them shouldn't work. As eromod said, you'd probably need to bake it. See http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/13509/11237

Comment: Did you unwrap the model? Did you bake the textures?

Answer (score 1):

Other formats than blenders .blend don't support Blenders full feature set, have different settings or similar functions, which are not always compatible. Not all Settings, Materials or Datatypes can be saved by export functions. So if you don't want to import your model in a different Program, use the `Save As` Function to save your file in the native **.blend** format.

Comment: Thanks for the answers, but my problem is when i export my file to .obj or .fbx, and then re import the .obj or .fbx it just gets grey and the pre build texture (pattern) like "marble" is not vissible. If i just put a color on a cube and export to .obj or .fbx and re import it works, and the color is visible.

Comment: .Obj only supports basic colors and image texture, not procedural texture such as marble.

Comment: @mathias This is the correct answer, and it should be marked as such.

Answer (score -3):

maybe try to "pack external data"?

File ‣ External Data ‣ Pack into blend-file

https://www.blender.org/manual//data_system/introduction.html#pack-unpack-data

Comment: Lets say i just make a simple glass, and i use the "glass bsdf" option in the material tab. How can i export my model to .obj or .fbx and keep that "glass effect"? when i re import my .obj or.fbx file to blender its just grey.

Comment: Oh, I think you need to bake it to a texture because its a cycles thing and not all programs have cycles.

Comment: the texture can be partially transparent like glass but other programs might not deflect light like cycles

Comment: Ok thanks for the answer, i will see if i can find out how to bake to a texture. Totaly new to blender, but seems like a very nice program for making models.

Comment: Im pretty new too, I started less than half a year ago. Its my new years resolution to read the entire Blender Reference Manual. With a minimum of three pages a day, I can make it. Its really hard to find the will power but I recommend it because its "comprehensive".