# How to give the "low poly" effect to a flat surface

Tags: workflow

I'm looking for a way to achieve this kind of effect; the ground path seems to have 'relief' but in fact it's flat; the character doesn't bump on it.

For now i'm starting with a plane; subdivide; displace (cloud); and then I select a bunch of faces which i scale-z to but even; i end up with a shitty flat surface with no color.

What am I doing wrong ?

[image: shitty]

[image: screen2]

Comment: You could render out your displaced plane and save it as an image. Then use the image as a texture.

Comment: Bake your low poly geometry to the flat surface using a bump map or normal map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bake the normals of the low poly object and use that as a texture on the plane.
With a Color Ramp you can change the colors of the normal map texture.

[image]

[How to bake in Cycles](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/13508/how-do-i-bake-a-texture-using-cycles-bake)