# How to bake Full Render In Blender

Tags: rendering, blender-internal-render-engine, baking

I am new to blender, my computer is too slow. I want to bake full render for faster rendering my animation. Please someone tell me how to bake full render.
thanks
There is my project file that I want to bake:
[MyHousePlane.blend](http://www.mediafire.com/file/sw19zcbz13u2szb/MyHousePlane.blend)

Comment: welcome! well, you can bake textures (see under render > baking panel) and all simulations (each has its "caching/baking panel)"... have you tried and are not working for you?

Comment: Does: [How do I bake a texture using Cycles bake](http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/13508/2217) help?

Comment: And Mr #David I want bake blender internal.

Comment: @m.ardito thanks for comment, so I tried but actually I don't know the workflow. I searched on go and also read bender manual  but nothing I got. Please give me some hint.

Comment: @Henry Hunter: I tried your model, it seems to have quite basic shapes, no simulations, cloths, someke, displacements, so what you could to is to bake... textures, basically. I don't know how much it could speed up your animation render, but this means you have to tell Blender to pre-calculate materials for all surfaces as a static image, that will be mapped to the surfaces. This is called UV mapping, and it needs some practice (I suggest you to learn on simpler models). You can read about Blender internal baking here: https://www.blender.org/manual/render/blender_render/bake.html.

Comment: @Henry Hunter also check duplicate vertices, you have many...