# Detail lost when cycles baking to texture

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, uv, texture-baking

I've been working on a model lately, and UV unwrapped and textured my mesh. After doing so, I added some dirty vertex colors to add some darker areas, and I wanted to bake it onto my regular texture. The problem is, that I lose vertex colors after baking.

Here's a picture or my rendered mesh with vertex colors, full detail:

[image]

As you can see, there are dark crevices throughout the model, which is desired. I've followed the directions in [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/13508/how-do-i-bake-a-texture-using-cycles-bake) post to bake the dirty vertex colors onto my texture. Here's the baked texture, when using type "Diffuse Color":

[image]

The largest sphere is where the body is mapped to. The texture, after baking, does not have sa many dark spots as the first image. It's apparent when I export it to Three.js with the texture:

[image]

As you can see, the whole back part of the mesh has no vertex colors. Why is that so? I have followed the directions exactly as in the post linked. Here are the applicable files:

[image]

[stage1.png - FileDropper](http://www.filedropper.com/stage1)

[stage1_REV.png - FileDropper](http://www.filedropper.com/stage1rev)

Comment: Please, pack your textures to blend file and upload .blend here  http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/  This is service for this forum and there are some reasons why should be used. :-) About your issue: 1: maybe low texture resolution, or 2: wrong unwraped - too stretched UVs. Upload your .blend here and I look at it :-)

Comment: @Shubol3D I was unaware of the service, thanks! I've edited the post.

Comment: You need to unwrap the torso with the seam on the bottom to have more even texture space distribution, right now the back part has a very low texture resolution comparing to the front.

Comment: @Denis Thanks for your response, I agree. The problem is that when I unwrap it takes a lot of time to space everything out and orient them. Would I have to completely create a new texture? Also, the seam does not seem to be unwrapping properly, download the new version [here](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/2325/) with new seam.

Comment: @AndrewLi the seam should be on the bottom from the head to the tail, also before unwrapping select all the uvs and use alt+p to unpin the vertices

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fix your problem you need to make a better texture distribution of the UVMap.

Easy way to do that is to create an additional UVMap with a seam going from the head to the tail on the bottom of the model.

Then select all UV islands, unpin the vertices using <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> while the mouse cursor is in the UV/Image editor window, and unwrap the model.

Make sure that the object, the new UVMap and the bake texture node are selected and bake the model.

[image]

The result:

[image]

Comment: By the looks of it, this yields the cleanest result. So just mark a seam at the very middle bottom of the mesh? Is there any quicker way to mark such a seam?

Comment: @AndrewLi yes and you can remove the seams where the spots are and unwrap in the new UV map.

Comment: So I'd have to one by one select the edges at the bottom? Seems a bit time consuming, how did you do it?

Comment: @AndrewLi Select one edge at one end then hold CTRL and select an edge at the other end.

Comment: It seems that unwrapping isn't quite desired. Since the file is now too large to upload, I'll take some screenshots: [here](https://i.gyazo.com/508dab3823b1eb12845c5f9753dd5cb6.png) and [here](https://i.gyazo.com/3435f74aca54b51d6c80668eed8bd0e3.png). Not sure if I 'unpinned the vertices' correctly.

Comment: @AndrewLi The seams are good but you didnt unpin, because the vertices show red in UVs, make sure that the mouse cursor is in the UV/Image editor while you are unpinning.

Answer (score 4):

Your problem is that your UVs in their present state are really bad for baking. This may seem to work for your other texture, but the UVs are heavily distorted in the main body area where you noticed the issue.

[image]

You can use "Smart UV Project" to get a decent set of baking UVs so that you don't need to waste time on it (make it a new UV so as not to overwrite the old one).

[image]

Here is a quick bake and the results in texture mode:

[image]