# Using metals in sketchfab

Tags: texturing, baking

I made a chair that has a procedural cycles leather texture. I`d like to bake this texture and set my model to shadeless rendering on sketchfab. But the chair structure is metal, and I can't bake it. How do I manage this? I want to use baked textures with Sketchfab metalness.

Maybe if I could transform my procedural texture in diffuse, normal and glossiness maps, then I could use only sketchfab textures and no need to baking them.

What's the best solution in this case? Is there a way to use baked textures with metal textures, or do I have to make maps for my procedural textures? And how do I do that?

Sorry for my english, it's not my native language

Answer (score 1):

"Metal" textures are often determined by a number of different textures working together to create the appearance of metal. These can include a number of things such as Diffuse, Specular, Normals, and glossy shaders. In order to make these usable by external programs you can either bake these maps individually of create a PBR material, which is basically a combination of all of the above.

There are lot's of tutorials on how you may create PBR materials in blender my favorite as always is from [Blender Guru](https://www.blenderguru.com/tutorials/pbr-shader-tutorial-pt1/).

However if you wish to export individual maps there is a great tutorial here on 
[stack exchange.](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/13508/how-do-i-bake-a-texture-using-cycles-bake)

Comment: Thanks for the answer.I'm using exactly Blender Guru PBR Metal texture for the structure of the chair. And I have a leather texture for other parts. My question is, what's the best way to export both textures to sketchfab?

Comment: Sorry for the late response. If you want to export everything together you will need to make sure all parts of the model are unwrapped together on the same map image. However it is impossible to combine different textures such as normal maps, diffuse maps, specular maps, etc. Into one singular texture as each one functions for a different purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Sketchfab supports PBR rendering which would mean exporting separate maps for Albedo (AKA Diffuse), Metalness, and then either Specular or Roughness maps.

But, you mention wanting to export to shadeless (unlit) rendering which can support PBR maps but doesn't give the PBR look. If you're looking for a stylistic choice for shadeless, then a metal look will need to be achieved with just a diffuse texture which may mean baking down a number of things like AO, light maps, diffuse to one texture. Hope this helps.

Comment: Albedo is not otherwise known as diffuse: http://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/a/351