# Is there any way to apply adaptive subdivision displacement to mesh?

Tags: texturing, modifiers, node-editor, subdivision-surface

Following Gleb Alexandrov's [tutorial](https://youtu.be/hlh9rrjG29k?t=1131) I made a cool displacement mountain material with adaptive subdivison and a few noise textures in the displacement output. For another project i need this same mountain model, but as real geometry rather than render-based since I want it 3d-printed.

Any way to apply the adaptive subsurf modifier or convert the material nodes into an image-displacement texture?

Comment: Your youtube link seems broken.

Comment: The link you provided doesn't work - can you check it to make sure it works on your end?

Comment: Please edit your question with the correct link.

Comment: Applying modifier is done [in the Modifiers tab](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/modifiers/introduction.html#interface) of the Properties editor (you need to have that modifier still in stack), [texture baking](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/13508/how-do-i-bake-a-texture-using-cycles-bake) is used for converting material nodes into image textures. It's not quite clear what setup do you have.

Comment: Wow, the timely response of BSE's finest! :)

Comment: Applying modifier doesn't work, as adaptive subdivision only modifies the object as it renders or in rendered viewport.

Comment: Adaptive subdiv is a feature of cycles, the generating and altering of extra mesh data is performed inside the cycles rendering engine after the mesh data has been sent for rendering. It may be possible that baking a normal map could work, but I don't expect there is a way to get the generated mesh data back from cycles.