# Multiple textures for one mesh

Tags: mesh

Okay so I am converting items for my own personal game play.The platform i use for my game requires one texture only but the items that I am converting has up to three or four different textures and come in as separate meshes. My goal is to have one item with the textures merged to fit into the merged mesh. I already know how to join the meshes I just need to know how to get the textures to align with the mesh.

Comment: It's not clear how you are using Blender here.

Comment: i have the item opened up in blender it has all the textures attached i want to merge the textures into one so i can extract the uv map

Comment: Look for texture baking. If you are using cycles: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/13508/how-do-i-bake-a-texture-using-cycles-bake/13509#13509

Answer (score 1):

Add a new UV set in the Properties panel [image: add uv set], and unwrap the mesh in Edit mode using that UV set. Open a new image texture in the UV Image Editor at the size you want the final to be, and in the Render tab of the Proiperties panel, open up the Bake tab. Select 'Textures' and then press 'Bake', and you should see your existing textures from the object appear in the new image. Save it, and then set it in the material's texture stack for actual use.

Comment: how do you add the new uv set? lol

Comment: see the edit above - in the properties panel, and you can add a new uv map.

Comment: i got all the other steps just didn't get what you meant by set it in the material's texture stack

Comment: "Texture Stack" is how I refer to the Texture Slots when looking at them in the material shader tab in the Properties panel. Some people will assume that the image is already in the material after baking, but you must manually add it to the material after saving the baked image.

Comment: found materials in the properties menu just need to to know how I would add the materials in manually and I am one of those that assumed the material would have been ready lol