# How to import/export textures created through nodes to UE4?

Tags: texturing, node-editor, export, import, unreal-engine

I am trying to export this rock model over to Unreal Engine 4. So far, i can import the mesh, but i cant figure out how to import the textures. keep in mind that the texture is made purely from Nodes (veroni, noise ect) so importing the .png isnt possible
[image: this is the rock that i have created using blender.]

[image: These are the nodes i have used to create the texture]

just to clarify, i would like to import the textures, made purely using nodes, into Unreal Engine 4 (if possible). 
Thanks

Comment: Try the solution to [this question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/13508/how-do-i-bake-a-texture-using-cycles-bake)

Comment: reply to first solution: it seems to have worked, i let everyone know if it does, thanks