# UV Map isn't colored

Tags: uv, uv-image-editor

My current UV Map looks like this:

[image]

I tried looking up a solution and couldn't find one. I either need the UV Map Image or for it to export with color as a .fbx file. Someone said something about when exporting as a .fbx to tick the "export vertex colors" option. But there isn't one?

Hopefully someone can help me out, I'd appreciate it, thanks:)

Comment: What are you trying to do? Is your intention to make a texture for the object? UV map can't be colored, it represents set of UV coordinates used for the mapping of the 3D object to 2D image. Export vertex colors is completely another way of storing colors in vertices and not using image at all.

Comment: I made a tree and I want to export the model into ROBLOX. However, when I export it, the color disappears. I used Cycles Render if that helps.

Comment: There isn't any information about how you colored the model. If that was done with Cycles materials then [bake textures](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/13508/how-do-i-bake-a-texture-using-cycles-bake) and use them in 3-rd party app. Other applications won't udnerstand Cycles materials.