# White borders on semi-transparent hair/eyelashes in material view

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, transparency, color, hair

I added hair and eyelashes textures to my character. They are PNG images and are partially transparent. I got white borders on the edges, but **they appear only in Material view**. If I switch to Rendered view, everything looks perfectly fine.

Here are screenshots of Material and Rendered views:
[image: screenshots]
[image: screenshots]

**Question #1**: Is there a way to remove those white borders in Material view? My settings for eyelashes are shown on the second screenshot. I already tried to use Alpha Clip option as it was suggested in similar topics, but it removes only part of the white border and part of it still stays.

**Question #2**: While it would be awesome to get rid of them, is it critical to remove those white borders at all since everything looks fine in Rendered view? When I eventually export this model to Unity, will it look like rendered version?

**UPDATE**: Looks like the problem was in partial transparency. When exported to Unity if I use "Transparent" rendering mode in material properties I get the same borders but I found the way to get rid of them. **Solution in Unity**: Use "Fade" option in rendering mode menu. This will remove the white borders and make both eyelashes and hair look normal.

Comment: This shouldn't be critical as long is it's only in Material shading mode. As to Unity you could check if it's actually lagging, likely it should work as it did when rendered, still this depends on how textures are baked (since you can't transfer Cycles materials directly)

Comment: You say you tried "Alpha Clip" (I assume this is in the Viewport Alpha setting).  Did you try "Alpha Sort" or "Alpha Blend"?  Might not help but it's worth trying.

Comment: @risingfall  I tried all of them... No changes.

Comment: @MrZak Ty for the info. I also have a feeling that it won't be affected since rendering looks ok. I'll try it later in Unity (need to learn more about "baking" first. gonna be my task for this evening..).

Comment: See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/13508/how-do-i-bake-a-texture-using-cycles-bake for general setup on Cycles baking. In your case you should choose Emit pass (since it's easier to catch) and plug your maps separately to Emit shader (Node Wrangler here), then bake one by one

Comment: @MrZak Cool, thanks. I'll report later if everything works fine.