# No objects or images found to bake to

Tags: texturing, baking, vertex-colors, vertex-paint

this is my first time trying to do this thing.

So I am trying to bake a Vector painted object onto a texture but I failled.

Video showing the failure: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tOjKZ9u3OD8

I tried and followed this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UwbmLsYTeyU) and when I did, it says "No objects or images found to bake to".

Hope you guys can help me.

And another thing to take note is that I was making this originally in Cycle and only changed to Blender Render when I wanted to bake it. That's probably the problem but I'm not sure how to fix it.

Comment: Did you save the empty image you created to your drive after you create it in blender?. Sometimes it causes error.

Comment: Cycles and Blender internal do not share the same materials. You can bake your materials in cycles to image textures and use those in blender internal, but you need to create new materials to use them. As for the workflow on how to render read: [How do I bake a texture in cycles?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/13508/how-do-i-bake-a-texture-using-cycles-bake)

Comment: @hawkenfox No I did not save it as an image. But I tried to just now and it didn't work either.

Comment: @cegaton I tried following that workflow but I don't think I get it. Can you help tell me the step by step to bake a VertexPainted object onto a Texture image of another object?