# Render sphere surface to HDRI?

Tags: texture-baking, baking

I want to bake the surface of a sphere to a equirectangular HDR texture. Is this possible?

For baking I did not find an option to bake HDR. My approach was to use a sphere with backfaceculling and a panorama camera inside it, but that results in different lighting as the normals are different:

[image]

The surface parameterization should support baking directly to HDR. Am I missing something? Help? :D

Something that I tried was rendering it as a mirror ball panorama, but the conversion to equirectangular resulted in some artifacts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When creating the image, check the *32 bit Float* option:

[image]

[Bake](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/13509/7777) whatever you want into the texture, in your case you want the *Combined* bake type. I suppose your sphere is correctly unwrapped into a square layout.

Your texture will have the full dynamic range you need.

Save the texture in your favorite format (Image Editor, <kbd>F3</kbd>), .hdr is an option.

Comment: Right! I looked in the render settings only... :D Works, thanks!