# Cycles Baking Produces Odd/Useless results

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, materials, baking

I'm testing Cycles Baking on an Aircraft body that I've been working on. I'm getting some really odd results. I'm using a NVIDIA GTX 970. I've applied all the modifiers except the subsurf on the plane body. I've re-unwrapped the mesh and removed doubles. I've also checked that the normals are correct. I'm using an HDR image for the lighting. For the model, the wings and the air intake (in front of the windshield) are separate objects. They are individually UV unwrapped with the same material applied, through I don't know if this would affect the baking.

**Actual Rendered Material**
[image]

**Baked Material Output**
[image]

**Baked Material Output (Reverse Side)**
[image]

**Bake Image**
[image]

**Settings:** 
Render Samples: 1024
Bake Settings:
[image]

**Node Setup**
I'm baking to the image texture node in the green frame.
[image]

Does anyone have an idea as to what is going wrong and how I can fix it? I'd appreciate the help!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I bake a texture using Cycles bake](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/13508/how-do-i-bake-a-texture-using-cycles-bake)

Comment: Are you trying to bake reflections? This is not a good idea.

Comment: A Brewster Buffalo?