# Attempting to assign faces, why isn't the material showing?

Tags: texture-baking

I'm trying to assign different materials to parts of this mesh. I've cornered off the areas and unwrapped them, but can't seem to get the material to show up in the UV Map. How do I assign/bake the texture so I can see it as a flat image on the map?

bear in mind, I'm by no means a seasoned user:

[image]

Comment: Materials don't show up in UV maps.  Ever.  Are you asking about texture images?  To get a particular image to show up, with the UV map laid over it, from the screen you're displaying, simply select your image from the image picker drop list, the part that currently says "SeatTut".

Comment: Okay, I understand that. With Maya I would "bake" the material and use the environmental lights and material render as a basis for drawing on in another paint program and then applying it as a texture afterward. I'm trying to achieve something similar, instead of painting the lights/shadow myself I just make it more glossy or matte and render it into a "baked" UV map. So that's what I'm trying to do here, have blender bake the mats into the corresponding UV island.

Comment: Okay, sorry, I didn't really understand that. In Blender it's called baking as well.  I think that if you look for "how to bake in Blender" you will find many hits, including existing answers on Blender Stack Exchange, such as https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/13508/how-do-i-bake-a-texture-using-cycles-bake .

Comment: it keeps telling me no active image found- though I believe I've assigned textures to both the material and the nodes. If I only wanted to bake part of the object would it still be the same method as the steps you've linked me? I'll try looking around for specifics more thoroughly.

Comment: Follow instructions exactly.  No active image found usually means you didn't have an active image texture in your nodes telling Cycles what to write to.  You can't bake part of an object; if you don't want to bake some mats, don't give them an active image, but it doesn't make it any faster, it still has to render everything to bake anything.

Comment: thank you for your help, Nathan! My apologies for not replying sooner. I found out that I had to create an image texture node. So simple, lol! Still struggling with why it bakes black though, despite the scene lights.