# How do I bake a flat texture in Cycles? (2.79)

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texture-baking

I've been looking on how to bake a texture from my material colors. I found a question from the past saying that there would be a bake option for "Diffuse Color" but I don't see that in the dropdown menu. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Related [How do I bake a texture using Cycles bake?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/13508/how-do-i-bake-a-texture-using-cycles-bake/13509#13509)

Comment: Nono, I need it to be flat, without lights or shadows and stuff. I just need the material colors into a texture and nothing else.

Answer (score 1):

First of all read about overall baking process in the link provided by Cegaton: [How do I bake a texture using Cycles bake](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/13508/how-do-i-bake-a-texture-using-cycles-bake/13509#13509)

Then the "trick" is pretty simple.

1. Connect your material colors to **Emission Shader**.
2. Select **Bake Type** as **Emit**.
3. Bake.

[image: final]

Answer (score 1):

Select "Diffuse" from the drop-down list
then click the "Color" button.
[image: Bake "Diffuse Color"]