# Can't bake in Render (or UV map)

Tags: mesh, texturing, uv, blender-internal-render-engine, texture-baking

All of my textures are showing up on the texture viewer and correctly assigned, however it won't let me bake. I'd like to bake to an ambient occlusion, to add some shadows, but it won't let me, saying 'no image or textures found'.

Here is the .dae file :

https://ufile.io/5o0tr

Thanks!

Comment: In the .dae file there are no textures. Go to File, External data, and choose "Pack All into .blend, then upload the .blend file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Observing the dae file I found the UV-Map to be unsuitable for baking because it overlaps on itself, so I followed [How do I bake a texture using Cycles bake](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/13508/how-do-i-bake-a-texture-using-cycles-bake) to bake with cycles, which worked quite well.

Starting with imported .dae, UV-Unwrapping, setting up the bake target.
[image: First]
Node setup, render setup and intial render process.
[image: Second]
Finishing the render finding overlaps, reducing overlap size
[image: Third]
Final render
[image: Fourth]
Complete workflow
[image: Complete]

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked, finally. Do you know how to add a 'shadowey' texture, like the one it is shown with the lamp or directly on the view windows? It doesn't appear at all when I export it.

Comment: I don't understand the question. From which program are you exporting and to which program?