# Custom material preview object?

Tags: materials, objects

Like in [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/132955/is-there-a-way-to-save-a-materials-preview) question, I am also talking about that material preview.

Is there a way to have custom *material* preview objects? In Blender 2.80 and before, there were a bunch of different objects not included in the material preview that are now in 2.81 and later. I.e. the shader ball, fluid material preview, etc.

Can I import objects like these, or other custom objects into Blender for material previews, or use a python script that does this? I really like the new material preview objects in 2.81, and would like to be able to see them in 2.79.