# How do you bake materials?

Tags: materials, baking

Okay, I'm trying to bake the coloured materials I've added to my model. But whenever I go to the Render tab > Bake > and select any of the options, I get an error at the top saying 'No active UV layer found in the object'. Well... Of course not. I've added materials, not textures. I've not had to do any UV unwrapping. What am I missing? What do I need to do to bake coloured materials?

Thanks

Comment: I've done a quick UV unwrap by selecting Project From View. I've created a new UV layout, but now when I go to bake, it says that no active image could be found in one of the materials. Well, duh... None of them have images; they're coloured materials.

Comment: I've ticked Selected to Active but it comes up with an error saying 'No selected valid objects'

Comment: Read [How do I bake a texture using Cycles bake?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/13508/how-do-i-bake-a-texture-using-cycles-bake/13509#13509)

Comment: If you want to add information to your question, please do so by editing it (edit link is right below it) and don't scatter them throughout the comments.

Comment: Doing that doesn't take the thread to the top of the page though, so people may not see it.

Comment: Okay, I have one more material colour I need to bake, which is a Glossy and Diffuse combined. It's supposed to be a shiny blue, but no matter what bake settings I adjust, the result doesn't look right. How should I set it up correctly?

Comment: I'm still having problems with this. I've made an image for each colour, but I can't get them applied when in Unity. I've tried making a UV image for the whole gun, but each part has its own material, so I can't really combine them.