# A problem understanding Materials and textures

Tags: texturing, materials

I new to blender and I'm sure that this is a simplistic problem but I said I'd ask here anyway. I have added materials and textures to a model. I want to export the materials and textures from blender to a .png file so that I can import the materials and textures to tabletop simulator.
what do I need to do to make this happen I've had a look around the internet and only found things referring to .png files you already have being added to a model.

Comment: The search term you need is "baking"

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures/57541#57541 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/13508/how-do-i-bake-a-texture-using-cycles-bake