# How do I archive my textures and mesh in the same archive?

Tags: materials

So I made some models in Blender and I want to upload them to CGTrader, however, I don't know how to zip them all up in a folder/archive. The farthest I've got is a .blend file zipped in an archive. I want to see all the textures listed in a folder and not just a single .blend file. Thnaks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You just need to bake your textures, which means exporting your object's texture in a image file, based on its UV unwrap.

You can check [this post](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/13508/how-do-i-bake-a-texture-using-cycles-bake) for info or you can google it yourself.