# How do I convert a material output from the node editor into a png image file? Blender 2.82

Tags: texturing, node-editor, image

I combined an image texture with a noise texture in the node editor and I just wanted to know if you could export both the image texture and the noise texture as a single png file.

Can you?

Comment: Hello :). Sure you can, it's called *texture baking*. https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/13508/