# How to export procedural material from blender to c4d

Tags: texturing, materials, export, workflow, texture-baking

I was wondering what's the best way for me to export my procedural material (mainly texture) with or without the mesh from blender to cinema 4d.

I have baked the normals. Is there another way such as exporting into certain file type?

Thank you

Comment: Hello :). You can bake the texture into an image file https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/13508/

Comment: Hi, thank you for the link. I applied the same rocedural material/texture to 4 mesh objects that I made. So do I first UV unwrap all of them or individually? and when I begin to bake texture for the objects to I select the 4 objects with the same texture and bake it or I select one object and bake the texture for it? Thank you.

Comment: Hello :). I'm not experienced with baking, but you can post a new question, if you're stuck.