# How to export lava texture to png?

Tags: uv, texture-baking

I made a lava texture and I'm trying to export it to a .png file, but when I do its all black. In the UV editor, it also shows the texture as black. Here is a picture[image: LavaTexture i made] edit: i did it but another glitch in adding other[image: the color is there but the texture is incorrectly mapped] pic, explanation, when I bake it, it just gives me that random weird purple texture which looks nothing like the lava texture. A kind person fixed the problem but another has occurred. [![
][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nbYHz.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nbYHz.png)

Comment: You have to bake the texture in Cycles Render mode. https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/13508/how-do-i-bake-a-texture-using-cycles-bake

Comment: but that is not 2.8?

Comment: i cant get the baking to work

Comment: help me ples i cant do it ples

Comment: when i bake it it just shows black texture

Comment: i urgently need this texture to make my roblox game pet egg

Comment: its all purple and weird

Comment: help me please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are baking the Normals instead of diffuse/color. Try this instead to get the diffuse Color only:

[image]

... but since it is a Lava material and if you have some emission, you may have to bake the emission pass as well. It all depends on how you want to use the baked texture for. May be something like this with Emission:

[image]

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH!

Comment: im a baker now lol

Comment: Great, could you accept my post as answer if it worked for you? That's kind of the principle of StackExchange. https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: yes i accepted it

Comment: i just have one small problem left but its an ez fix probably for u

Comment: ill post pic in edit