# Can I somehow bake the Cycles material to use in Evee?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, eevee-render-engine, baking

The thing is I have an Evee scene that looks fine except for one object that looks better in Cycles, it looks similar in Evee, but not that good, so I thought it would be awesome if I could somehow print the way material looks in Cycles to use that approximation in Evee...
Also I`ve never done baking yet so I can be mistaken a lot

Comment: Sure: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/13508/how-do-i-bake-a-texture-using-cycles-bake

Comment: thanks, I`ll try it. I just thought baking from Cycles to use in Cycles later would differ from baking in Cycles to use in Evee